# Bone Rotation results in object being Flipped / Mirrored

Tags: animation, bones, constraints

I'm animating the fold of a paper object.
I added a Child Of constraint to the objects, and the target is a bone. The bone is parented to the next object.
When I go into Pose mode and rotate the bone, it flips / mirrors after it goes past 90 degrees. (see this video i made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6BACzgD6hA )
What am I doing wrong?

The file: [image]

[image]

Comment: hello, your link doesn't work, please edit your post

Comment: Hello, I updated the YouTube link. Hope it works now.

Comment: maybe share just this part of your object so that we can try? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added the file to the question :)

Comment: it has to do with the Child Of constraint, technically I don't know why it flips passed the 90° (it may have to do with the way bone rotation work?), but you can fix the problem by rotating the object's origin (Options > Affect Only > Origins) 180° on the Z axis in order to align its orientation with the bone, you could also choose another constraint, like the Rotation constraint (Axis > Y, Invert > Y, Target > Local Space, Owner > Local Space), or simply parent the object to the bone with a Ctrl P > Bone.